# What is the conversion then for MH/s to GH/s and so on

Tags: hashpower, terminology

I've seen this answer and maybe I'm just tired

- [What is the difference between kH/s, MH/s, and GH/s?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/what-is-the-difference-between-kh-s-mh-s-gh-s/9220#9220)

> - 1 kH/s is 1,000 hashes per second (sometimes mistakenly written KH/s).
> - 1 MH/s is 1,000,000 hashes per second.
> - 1 GH/s is 1,000,000,000 hashes per second.
> - 1 TH/s is 1,000,000,000,000 hashes per second.

so if I have 1 TH/s I would have

```
1000 GH/s?
```

and 1 GH/s would be

```
1000 MH/s
```

or am I missing the math here?