# Gigahash vs Megahash

Tags: bitcoind

So, 1 GHash equals 1000 Mhash's as far as I know. Then, why genesis-mining measures the bitcoin hashpower in terrahashes?? 1 Thash = 1000 Ghash. The whole hashocean is said to have 41.6 GH/s. On genesis you can buy 1 Thash for 400$. Who is naming their units in incorrect way?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9219/5406

Answer (score 1):

Your 41.6 GH/s is certainly wrong. According to https://bitcoinwisdom.com/bitcoin/difficulty it's currently 757,561,871 GH/s = 757,561 TeraHash/s.

Also: it's "Tera", one r and capital T. Capitalization is important in the Metric prefixes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

Note also that cloud mining is usually a scam. Why would they give you money? Answer: they don't.

Answer (score 1):

As the network gets bigger, the reference hashpower for the whole network grows too. The bitcoin network is now in the petahash range and soon will be exahashes!

1000    k   kilo

1000^2  M   mega

1000^3  G   giga

1000^4  T   tera

1000^5  P   peta

1000^6  E   exa

1000^7  Z   zetta

1000^8  Y   yotta