# Calculating daily mined BTC

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-reward, difficulty

Hopefully an easy Question. I was updating some data tables and wanted to estimate monthly yield based on difficulty and known hashrate of the miner in this cash 110 TH/S.

I had it in my head the formula would be =(110,000,000 * 6.25 * 600 * 30)/67.31 or =(H/S * reward * seconds * days / difficulty)

I'm wildly off, and could use some assistance. I was using the below reference cells when attempting to calculate. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: I think I fixed it. I didn't use the full network difficulty *face palm*. I'm now getting the expected yields.

Comment: 110,000,000 H/s are only 110 MH/s. You are missing a factor of 1,000,000 (see e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/21498/5406). Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/135/5406 answer your question?

Comment: Something is still off then. Cause If 1 Th/S = 1,000,000,000,000, 110 would =  110,000,000,000,000. Using my same formula and accounting for network difficulty of  67,305,906,902,031.00, I am getting 6,129 BTC yield...Which is massively off the mark.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two methods to calculate an estimate for your profitability.

## 1. Your share of the reward is proportional to your share of the hashrate

There are an expected 144 blocks per day each producing a subsidy of 6.25 ₿. That’s an expected total of 900 new bitcoins per day. Your miner has 110 TH/s (1.1×10<sup>14</sup> H/s). Mining pools are [currently self-reporting](https://miningpoolstats.stream/bitcoin) a total hashrate of 525.35 EH/s (5.2535×10<sup>20</sup> H/S).
Your expected revenue `R` is a proportion of the total reward equal to your proportion of the hashrate:

```
R / 900 ₿ = 110 TH/s / 525.35 EH/s  
R = 900 ₿ × 1.1E14 / 5.2535E20  
R = 90,000,000,000 sats × 1.1 / 5,253,500  
R = 18,844.6 sats
```

Obviously this would be increased by the fees collected by these blocks and the increased block production we see most of the time.

## 2. Your revenue is proportional to the number of hashes you produce compared to the expected hashes it takes to find a block

```
H    your hashrate in Hash/s
D    the current difficulty
S    the block subsidy
R    your revenue per day
```

Finding a block takes an [expected D×2<sup>48</sup>/65,535 hashes](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5557/5406). The [current difficulty](https://btc.com/stats/diff) is 67,305,906,902,031. There are 60×60×24 = 86,400 seconds per day.

```
R = H × seconds_per_day × S / (D×2^48/65,535)
R = H × 86,400 × S × 65,535 / (D×2^48)
R = 1.1e14 H/s × 3600×24 s × 6.25 ₿ × 65,535 / (67,305,906,902,031×2^48) = 0.000205479 ₿
R = 20,457.9 sats
```

I used the current subsidy for the reward of a block here, but you would have to adjust that with the expected fees collected which currently are significant.
Checking my calculation against the results of [Nicehash’s profitability calculator](https://www.nicehash.com/profitability-calculator) puts the above estimates in the right ballpark when considering the recent substantial fees:

[image: Result of plugging the same values into Nicehash’s profitability calculator estimates a an approximate income of 28,252 sats.]

Comment: Can you explain how you got D×2^48? I was tracking from other sources around 2^32 (can't vouch for accuracy)

Comment: 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 is a very close estimate, but the actual value is 2^48/65,535 = 4,295,032,833. See e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5557/5406